# How can I have a default file selected for opening in an NSOpenPanel?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsopenpanel

The old way was `[ MyPanel runModalForDirectory: thedir file: thefile ]`, and the panel would open in the specified directory with the specified file already selected.

That's deprecated; we're supposed to use runModal now, but I don't see any way to set the selected file name.  I've tried including it in the string for setDirectoryURL, I've tried setRepresentedFilename, I've tried setNameFieldStringValue ... obviously it's possible to do this somehow, but I'm not having any luck with the internet search terms I've chosen, nor with Apple's documentation....

Thanks if you can help!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation lists [`setDirectoryURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000309-SW24) & [`setNameFieldStringValue:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000309-SW24) as available in 10.6 and above:

```
NSString *defaultDirectoryPath, *defaultName;
NSOpenPanel *openPanel;
...
[openPanel setNameFieldStringValue:defaultName];
[openPanel setDirectoryURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:defaultDirectoryPath]];
[openPanel runModal];
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, but as I said, I tried setDirectoryUrl, though maybe not properly. It opens the panel with the _directory_ selected, but not the file, even if I append it to the path.  What I want is for the open dialog to appear with the last file I opened already selected, so that if I hit the down-arrow once, it moves to the very next file (so I can open files in succession without losing my place).  I have not yet found out how to do this with runModal, but it's obviously possible, as Apple apps include that functionality....

Comment: Have you tried using `setNameFieldStringValue:` in conjunction with `setDirectoryURL:`? It's not totally clear from the docs, but one could interpret *Sets the filename in the name field to the specified value.* as meaning something close to the behaviour you're after. Not @ my mac right now so I can't test.

Comment: I haven't tried both of them together, and now I see that you had included setNameFieldStringValue in your post above, which I did not notice before.  But I had tried setNameFieldStringValue by itself and saw no behavioral change.  I'll try both together now ... naaaw, I've tried a few combos and it's not happening....

Comment: @Photovore I'm interested to know if the combined functionality matches my assumptions!

Comment: Didn't do what I wanted it to, sorry.  But thanks for trying!  Plus, your suggestion may well be the way to do it, but perhaps I am using it wrong....  For now, I'll stick with the deprecated method!...